# AWS Redshift Serverless IAM Identity Center Autnethication not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-redshift-serverless, aws-iam-identity-center

I am trying to use Redshift Query Editor V2 authenticating via IAM Identity Center. These were my setup steps:

- Created IAM Identity Center in the same region as the Serverless Workgroup
- Created a Serverless Redshift instance (note I tried both private and publicly accessible workgroup, also being deployed on public subnets)
- Create IAM Identity Center Application via the Redshift console and I have enabled the Query editor v2 application
- Added the IAM IdC group containing my user (which is a group that has Administrator privilieges, therefore it is not a credentials limitation issue)
- In Redshift (accessing it as superuser) I created an identity provider with this query:

```sql
CREATE IDENTITY PROVIDER "redshift-idc-app" TYPE AWSIDC
NAMESPACE 'awsidc'
APPLICATION_ARN 'arn:aws:sso::123456789012:application/ssoins-12345f67fe123d4/apl-a0b0a12dc123b1a4'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```

Note the role has this trust relationship

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                    "redshift.amazonaws.com",
                    "redshift-serverless.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:SetContext"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and these permissions:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "redshift:DescribeQev2IdcApplications",
                "redshift-serverless:ListNamespaces",
                "redshift-serverless:ListWorkgroups"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Sid": "AllowRetrievalOfRSMetadata"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "sso:DescribeApplication",
                "sso:DescribeInstance"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:sso::597598337678:application/ssoins-69876c8b1312f277/*",
                "arn:aws:sso:::instance/ssoins-69876c8b1312f277"
            ],
            "Sid": "AllowCreationOfIdPProvider"
        }
    ]
}
```

I ensured the role was created as expected:

```sql
SELECT * FROM SVV_IDENTITY_PROVIDERS;
```

- Finally I created a role in Redshift with the namespace of the provider for the group that I assigned in the group section of the `IAM Identity Center connection` application:

```sql
CREATE ROLE <idcnamespace:rolename>;

-- See the available roles
SELECT * FROM SVV_ROLES;
```

and assign permissions on a schema inside one of the databases (note that I pre-created the schema in the given database as well):

```sql
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA <schema> TO ROLE "<idcnamespace:rolename>";
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA <schema> TO ROLE "<idcnamespace:rolename>";
```

When I try to login I get this error on the QEV2 console: `Databases couldn't be listed`. However upon further investigation on Cloudtrail I can see these details on the event:

```json
{
"errorCode": "InternalServerErrorException",
    "requestParameters": {
        "path": "/cluster/connect/",
        "data": "***",
        "version": "1.001"
    },
    "responseElements": {
        "result": false,
        "code": "ContainerStateException",
        "error": "Cannot get container for user AROAYWI5C7KHET6MY5CL5:<USERNAME>",
        "message": "Cannot get container for user AROAYWI5C7KHET6MY5CL5:<USERNAME>"
    }
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation about this specific error. I basically followed [this AWS guide](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/integrate-okta-with-amazon-redshift-query-editor-v2-using-aws-iam-identity-center-for-seamless-single-sign-on/) step by step, yet no luck unfortunately :(
Any help of what I might have messed up in the setup or elsewhere is much appreciated :)

### UPDATE

The AWS team is probably working on something here, because now for the same setup/steps, the error has changed to an `ISACGetSessionException`.

```json
"responseElements": {
        "result": false,
        "code": "ISACGetSessionException",
        "error": "Cannot get session information from ISAC",
        "message": "Cannot get session information from ISAC"
}
```

Can't really tell what the hell is going on here. I wish the AWS team was a bit more transparent on disclaiming that the IDC integration with Redshift Serverless is "experimental" to say the least... Will keep anyone posted on updates

Comment: I am having the same problem but using provisioned cluster rather than serverless.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I assumed it was only a serverless issue since it is a relatively new service/option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One likely reason is that third-party cookies from amazon.com to amazonaws.com are blocked by your browser. You can check if this is happening in the Network tab by inspecting the Cookies on the sqlworkbench api requests. Check "show filtered out request cookies" to see whether these cookies are being blocked. You can see them highlighted in yellow.
[image: Filtered out cookies from a request in the Network tab of devtools]

The way to unblock these cookies will depend on the browser you're using. In Google Chrome, you can allow them by clicking the eye icon at the right end of the address bar.
[image: Google Chrome dialog to allow third-party cookies]

You may then have to Delete Connection and then Create Connection.
[image: Delete connection button highlighted in Redshift]
[image: Create connection button in Redshift]

Comment: It was a cookie issue. Thank you very much Kyle :)

Answer (score 0):

I have just been working on the same setup and all worked fine for a spell but then we also started seeing the same message "Databases couldn't be listed"

After the initial setup as described by yourself, we went onto granting the idcnamespace:rolename roles grants to other roles.

e.g.

`grant role "my_role" to role <idcnamespace:rolename>`

"my_role" was then granted access to relevant tables/schema etc

This worked fine at first but then after some time, it was as if there were no permissions.

Just got off call with AWS and it seems as if role chaining like this is potentially the cause of the issue and isn't fully supported yet so we have been advised to default back to granting table/schema access directly to idcnamespace:rolename.

Not sure if this is of help to you but thought would respond just in case

EDIT: This is still problematic after the above. Will post back if I get another response from AWS though OP confirmed is not the same issue anyway

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing. It is truly appreciated :)  In my case though, I am just using default roles for the idc:role. So that's not really it for me still :/

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Kyle, it was actually a Cookies issue. Since cookies are being requested from different `.amazon.com` subdomains, your browser should block some of them.

To be honest, I think AWS should handle this better on their end and at the very least document this a bit better.

Either way, here is **how you can solve this issue**.

I am using Brave, but the procedure should be very similar for any browser you might be using

1. Access the browser settings
2. Find a *Privacy - Security* section that mentions `Third-party cookies`
3. **suggestion** Keep block third-party cookies enabled (it is not a good idea to disable this security feature. Especially if you plan to use the browser for work, financial operations etc.)
4. Add this **wildcard domain** `[*.]amazon.com` as **allowed to use third-party cookies**

If you were already logged-in, just start a new Redshift connection to ensure cookies get set properly.

Hope this can save you a headache and once again, many thanks to @Kyle for pointing us to the solution.

Have a good one everybody